# FD_ISSET always true even if there is no new data?

Tags: c++, recv

I am trying to check if a client has send some new data. This actually tells me that i always have new data:

```
bool ClientHandle::hasData()
{
    fd_set temp;
    FD_ZERO(&temp);
    FD_SET(m_sock, &temp);

    //setup the timeout to 1000ms
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 1000;
    //temp.fd_count possible?
    if (select(m_sock+1, &temp, nullptr, nullptr, &tv) == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(m_sock, &temp)) 
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I am connecting with a java client and send a "connection" message which i read inside of the ctor:

```
ClientHandle::ClientHandle(SOCKET s) : m_sock(s)
{
    while (!hasData())
    {
    }
    char buffer[5];
    recv(m_sock, buffer, 4, NULL);
    auto i = atoi(buffer);
    LOG_INFO << "Byte to receive: " << i;
    auto dataBuffer = new char[i + 1]{'\0'};
    recv(m_sock, dataBuffer, i, NULL);
    LOG_INFO << dataBuffer;
    //clean up
    delete[] dataBuffer;
}
```

This seems to work right. After that i keep checking if there is new data which always is true even if the java client does not send any new data.

Here is the java client. Don't judge me it's just for checking the connections. It wont stay like this to send the size information as char[].

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException {
    Socket soc = null;

    soc = new Socket("localhost", 6060);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            soc.getInputStream()));

    if (soc != null)
        System.out.println("Connected");
    out.write("10\0");
    out.flush();
    out.write("newCon\0");
    out.flush();    
    out.close();
    in.close();
    soc.close();
}
```

So what is wrong with the hasData FD_ISSET method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is wrong with the hasData FD_ISSET method?

Actually no. There is a problem with your use of `recv()`.

`recv()` will return `0` if the client is disconnected and will return this until you `close` the socket (server-side). You can find this information [in the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv).
Even if `recv()` returns `0`, it will "trigger" `select()`.

Knowing that, it's easy to find out the problem: you never check the return value of `recv()` and so you're unable to say if the client is still connected or not. However, you still add it with `FD_SET`!

```
#include <sys/types.h> // for ssize_t
#include <stdio.h> // for perror()
ClientHandle::ClientHandle(SOCKET s) : m_sock(s)
{
    while (!hasData())
    {
    }
    char buffer[5];
    ssize_t ret = recv(m_sock, buffer, 4, NULL);
    if (ret == -1) // error
    {
        perror("recv");
        return ;
    }
    else if (ret == 0) // m_sock disconnects
    {
       close(m_sock);
       // DO NOT FD_SET m_sock since the socket is now closed 
    }
    else
    {
        auto i = atoi(buffer);
        LOG_INFO << "Byte to receive: " << i;
        auto dataBuffer = new char[i + 1]{'\0'};
        recv(m_sock, dataBuffer, i, NULL);
        LOG_INFO << dataBuffer;
        //clean up
        delete[] dataBuffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: so, the has data is fine but as i see out of other answers it will return true in also different conditions. (not just if it contains new data what i thought) so the hasdata method isn't right. So i need to add this somehow.

Comment: @BennX `hasData()` is almost correct: you should not use `FD_SET` on a disconnected socket. `recv()` returns a positive number if it gets data, `0` if the client disconnects and `-1` if an error occured. I updated my answer to add more explanation.

Comment: So to check if i got data i simply recv and handle it if there is new? I thiought i can check it with select before i try to optain data.

Comment: @BennX `recv()` simply receive data. `select()` allows you to `recv()` at the right moment. [Beej's Guide To Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) is a helpful ressource, you should take a look at it.

Comment: I already know that guide but i guess i need to read it in depth again. I just tried to check if there is data from the client before i recv but i see that it doesn't work as i expected. Do you maybe add a "correct" hasData if this is somehow possible? I think i'd need to combine it as something like "getData" which automatically checks and returns 0 if not or such.

Comment: @BennX : You need to split `hasData()`: one part for the insertion of elements into the fd set, the other one to call `select()`.

Answer (score 1):

From Steven's book UNIX Networking Programming:

A socket is ready for reading if any of the following four conditions is true:

- The number of bytes of data in the socket receive buffer is greater than or equal to the current size of the low-water mark for the socket receive buffer. A read operation on the socket will not block and will return a value greater than 0 (i.e., the data that is ready to be read). We can set this low-water mark using the SO_RCVLOWAT socket option. It defaults to 1 for TCP and UDP sockets.
- The read half of the connection is closed (i.e., a TCP connection that has received a FIN). A read operation on the socket will not block and will return 0 (i.e., EOF).
- The socket is a listening socket and the number of completed connections is nonzero. An accept on the listening socket will normally not block, although we will describe a timing condition in Section 16.6 under which the accept can block.
- A socket error is pending. A read operation on the socket will not block and will return an error (–1) with errno set to the specific error condition. These pending errors can also be fetched and cleared by calling getsockopt and specifying the SO_ERROR socket option.

ISSET is going to return true in all the cases above. After your Java client closes the connection, the socket will be ready for reading in the server.

In ClientHandle::ClientHandle you are not checking the return value of recv and if any data is returned.

Is it blocking in the second call to recv?

Comment: I see, so the hasData is actually not correct. Do you may post a correct way of checking if the client has new data?  It should be blocking but since i flush between these calls it does not block and work fine.

Comment: @BennX, Just check the return value of the first recv for error or for 0 (zero) data. If return value is 0 and it read 0 data then the connection was closed. If the return value is != 0, check for the error. Only call the second recv if the first was a successful read of >0 Bytes

Answer (score 1):

You don't check the return value of `recv` and you don't handle receiving fewer bytes than you asked for. So what do you expect to happen when the connection is closed?